# .htaccess RewriteEngine favicon issue

Tags: .htaccess, favicon

Here is my .htaccess file in public_html :

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /

DirectoryIndex /index.html

Redirect /index.html http://mysite.com/home.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpeg|jpg|ico|svg|eot|woff|ttf|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^page/ page%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

As you can see I set the website to load `.html` files from `/page/`. Unfortunately this method seems to be getting me in some trouble. First of all the favicon won't load (yes it is in the right place with proper `href`). I even added `|ico|` to that line of code in `.htaccess`. Any ideas on why jpgs etc. have no problem loading but the .ico fails?

Second, my site uses @fontface and i'm a little worried that `.svg .eot .woff` and `.ttf` font files might also fail due to the `.htaccess` trickery. I added those file extensions to the line of code in `.htaccess` but have no way of testing on various computers that might need the different font formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the condition to only fire the rules for your pages

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php|html?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^page/ page%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This is easier because you won't have to worry about all the different file types that could get wrongly redirected with your rule. To answer what's breaking your existing rule you would have to share your site's directory structure and the files' location.

Comment: Great answer. To add to it - in my case the favicon issue was a browser problem. I had to clear the cache AND restart the browser (Firefox). And yes it makes more sense in this case to dictate what is affected by the .htaccess rules rather than what is NOT affected. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing what solved your problem. +1 to your question. Browsers can get possessive on favicons especially if the URL has been bookmarked as well. They won't refresh even if the favicon file/size changes.

Comment: Nicely put up question and very good answer, +1 to both of you